# Diff using filenames only

Tags: diff

Is it possible using any sort of diff utility to diff based on filename only, ignoring all folders and subfolders?

So if I have

```
/folder_1/a/1243.txt
```

and

```
/folder_2/b/1243.txt
```

or

```
/folder_2/1234.txt
```

It would match the files when doing a diff between folder_1 and folder_2?

Comment: I don't quite get why this is language-agnostic. Are you interested in any solution at all or an algorithm (seems obvious)? Could you specify the problem more clearly, the current one is open to misinterpretation.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do a diff on lists of filenames, to see which filenames one folder contains that the other doesn't?  If so, do `find folder_1 -type f` in Linux or `dir /s /b /ad folder_1` in DOS and pipe the output into text files, then diff the contents of the text files.

In Vim I'd skip the temp files, and do `:.!find folder_1 -type f` in one window, `:.!find folder_2 -type f` in second window, then `:windo diffthis` to diff them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the help:

```
diff -q directory1 directory2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
diff -r directory another
```

compares the files in directories and outputs if they differs, or is missing from either of the directory.